# submit 1000 rows into db on ajax call makes ajax call hang

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq

I make an ajax call which result in inserting about 1000 rows into db, until that is done, ajax call is hanging and waiting for response. on ajax call i call my CreateNotification method.

What is the best way to implement this to prevent ajax call to hang?

```
 public static void CreateNewNotification(Guid UserGuid, string text, Guid questionGuid, string userName)
       {
           Notification notification;
           LinqConnectionDataContext context = new LinqConnectionDataContext();

           string baseUrl = text;

       var listOfFolowers = Folower.getMyFolowers(UserGuid);

       if (listOfFolowers.Count() != 0)
       {
           foreach (var item in listOfFolowers)
           {
               notification = new Notification();
               notification.Url = baseUrl;
               notification.UidCreationUser = UserGuid;
               notification.UidFolowerUser = item.FolowerUserId;
               notification.Text = userName + "just answered a question - " +text;
               notification.Uid = Guid.NewGuid();
               notification.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
               notification.Checked = false;
               context.Notifications.InsertOnSubmit(notification);
           }

       }

       try
       {
           context.SubmitChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {

       }


   }
```

Comment: is that the ajax function you r calling

Comment: no, ajax function is calling this method, ajax part is fine, i just need to figure out how to prevent it from hanging

Comment: Do you need a response for the client after updating these 1000 lines? If not, use a Thread to update the lines asynchronously and return directly after starting the thread so that the client doesn't hang until the lines are submitted.

Comment: For this many insertions, consider using a bulk copy process rather than LINQ to SQL/EF. The ORM solutions require 1000 requests to the database. I've seen drastic perf improvement when using Bulk Copy which would likely eliminate your timeout issue.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of scenario you can use ajax partial postback methods. By using partial postback you can control your queries. Also using any other methods to insert bulk data. This hang is because database time expiration.